# BigQuery Search which results in Error: Scalar subquery produced more than one element

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Running this query on BigQuery but resulting in this error: Error: Scalar subquery produced more than one element

```
select * 
from CRM.organizations 
where name LIKE (select org_name from CRM.deals where UUID is not null and status = 'won')
```

Is it possible to look for similar strings when the similarity is to a list of entries?

Comment: please do not change the question when answer is already provided! if you have new/more questions - post it as a new one with all relevant details and we will try to help you further! Also, make sure you don't ask multiple questions in one question!

Answer (score 0):

Use below - `IN` instead of `LIKE`

```
select * from CRM.organizations where name IN (
select org_name from CRM.deals 
where UUID is not null and status = 'won')
```

Comment: Would that not return all Entries with the exact same name, as opposed to those similar (the duplicates don't share the exact same name, they are missing the company incorporation name)

Comment: my answer addresses "Error: Scalar subquery produced more than one element" that is a title and looked to me an actual question of your post.